# Pass password in remote using rsync

Tags: jenkins, ant

As part of project, I prepared a Ant script which will download files from SVN and copy the files to remote server using scp.

But client asked me to copy only changed files from next deployment onwards in Jenkins instead of copying complete set of 20+ MB files.

got rsync command to do this but here the problem, how to send password from Ant

```
<exec executable="rsync" dir="/copy-files/js/" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="-rcv"/>
   <arg value="${username}@server:/media/js/"/>
</exec>
```

How to pass password from Jenkins, tried with RSYNC_PASSWORD and password-file options but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values for environment variables by using nested `env` elements:

```
<exec executable="rsync" dir="/copy-files/js/" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-rcv"/>
    <arg value="${username}@server:/media/js/"/>
    <env key="RSYNC_PASSWORD" value="[your.password]" />
</exec>
```